# NotificationCenter.observer not listening to Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I am facing a frustrating issue with NotificationCenter and I can't find what is wrong with my code. I don't know if there are any other settings to it but somehow my notificationcenter is either not firing or the observer is not listening to the notification.

I have in my viewcontroller1.swift

```
@IBAction func onButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .namePassedNotification, object: self)
    }
```

and in my viewcontroller2.swift

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotification), name: .namePassedNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleNotification()
    {
        view.backgroundColor = .black
    }
```

I've tried everything I can think of or find here on stackoverflow but nothing seem to work

Comment: It will never be called because you have added addObserver in the second view controller which is not in a view controller stack so, just change the view controller code. Add addObserver in the first view controller and post observer in the second view controller.

Comment: You don't add a notification observer in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Have you tried using the protocol - delegate communication here? Another question is: When you set the observer on viewcontroller2, is viewcontroller1 in the navigation stack (Is the controller still in memory)? Please describe the connection between these two controllers.

Comment: @RajaKishan sorry, it was a typo when posting the question but yeah. Using just self which refers to viewcontroller2 also fails to yield any result

Comment: @ElTomato removing the observer from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear also gave me the same result as before

Comment: @Srdjan I'm using a protocol - delegate communication doesn't suit what I want to achieve neither does using a closure. Also, yes, viewcontroller1 is still in the navigation stack connected to viewcontroller2 through a segue which is performed once another button is pressed

Comment: My point is add observer in first view controller and post it from second view controller.

Comment: @RajaKishan why? Because viewcontroller1 comes first before viewcontroller2. And viewcontroller one is the one that fires the action. So how will that work. I mean listening before posting a notification

Comment: Because when you pressed button from first view controller at that time second view controller is not initialise and not in navigation stack so there is no any listener added.

Comment: Thanks @RajaKishan it worked. But is there any way I can do it vice versa?

Comment: Need a more details. What's your scenario for making this?